# How to access OSGI console of wso2 carbon remotely

Tags: cmd, osgi, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a carbon instance running on one machine and i want to access it from another machine is it possible?

My requirement is ,i have Started wso2 carbon in OSGI console mode (`wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole`)

I want to add features into that carbon instance.. using provaddrepo and provinstall command.. I want to do this from a remote machine??

Is it possible to do that... suppose 3 nodes are running the carbon(osgi console mode),i need to access it from a remote machine to execute the commands ( like to install features using prov commands)

Is it possible,any script is there to do like that,how to connect that cmd instance from another machine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access OSGI console from a remote host, start it specifying the port number :

```
wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole=19444
```

And to access it from the remote host :

```
telnet hostname 19444
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Is is possible to do securely, using authentication.. I tried the above scenario,but without authenticating,we can access it remotely,that is something not good right?

Comment: Sure, OSGI console access should be reserved to an administrator in a production environment, but sorry, I can't help you to configure authentication on this remote access

Comment: In wso2 apim 4.0.0 this doesn't work and it seems to be broken since version 3.1

See Github [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8117)